# Language switcher with PHP with a two dimensional array in short syntax

Tags: php

I like to create a language switcher for a website in three languages.
It would be nice to use a multidimensional array in the shorthand syntax.

Unfortunately I'm completely new to PHP, therefor it is difficult to find a script, which I only have to edit for my purpose.

The situation, which is a standard usecase I suppose:
There's a website with 3 languages (for the example I use 3 different pages for each lanuage).

```
https://example.tld/de/
https://example.tld/en/
https://example.tld/fr/

https://example.tld/de/zimmer
https://example.tld/en/rooms
https://example.tld/fr/chambres

https://example.tld/de/seminarbereich
https://example.tld/en/seminar-area
https://example.tld/fr/zone-seminaires
```

Can I use the following two dimensional array to solve the task?

```
$myarray = [
['de', 'en', 'fr'], //language and as well the first part of the url
['Sprachumschalter', 'Language Switcher', 'Sélecteur de langue'], //aria-label
['Diese Seite auf Deutsch', 'This page in English', 'Cette page en français'], //title
['', '', ''], // page 1, start page of each language
['zimmer', 'rooms', 'chambres'], // page 2
['seminarbereich', 'seminar-area', 'zone-seminaires'] // page 3
]
```

The result in form of HTML5 on each page should be - here in form of the page "rooms":

```
<nav aria-label="Sprachumschalter">
    <ol>
        <li class="aktiv"><a href="/de/zimmer" lang="de" title="Diese Seite auf Deutsch">de</a></li>
        <li><a href="/en/rooms" lang="en" title="This page in English">en</a></li>
        <li><a href="/fr/chambres" lang="fr" title="Cette page en Français">fr</a></li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

Can you give me please a hint, where I can find a script which uses a comparable two dimenisional array for such a purpose?

I suppose I need a script which "asks"

"if the first of the url is 'de' than go to the array to position '...' and pick the appropriate content".

If there's someone who likes to help me, I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [gettext](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.gettext.php) instead of multi dimentional arrays

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your structure like this:

```
$array = [
    ["de"] => [
         ["label"] => "Sprachumschalter",
         ["title"] => "Diese Seite auf Deutsch",
         ["page"] => ["", "zimmer", "seminarbereich"]
    ],
    ["en"] => [
         ["label"] => "Language Switcher",
         ["title"] => "This page in English",
         ["page"] => ["", "rooms", "seminar-area"]
    ],
    ["fr"] => [
         ["label"] => "Sélecteur de langue",
         ["title"] => "Cette page en français",
         ["page"] => ["", "chambres", "zone-seminaires"]
    ]
]
```

Get URI Segments in PHP

```
https://example.tld/language/

$uriSegments = explode("/", parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));

echo $uriSegments[1]; //returns language

$language = $uriSegments[1];
```

So in your arra you can access to the information as follows:

```
var_dump($array[$language]); // get language data
echo $array[$language]["label"]; //get label
```

So for get your page you can create a counter that started in 0;

```
$counterPage = 0;

echo $array[$language]["page"][$counterPage]; //get the page
```

I hope I've helped you with an idea for how to solve it;

Comment: Thanks a lot for that helpful hints, Daniel. And thanks to the others in this thread too.

I copied your code example of the array and as well 

`$uriSegments = explode("/", parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));

echo $uriSegments[1]; //returns language`

But I get the error message "Fatal error: Illegal offset type in .../test.php on line 13

Line 13 contains:
`["label"] => "Sprachumschalter",`

Comment: your welcome, maybe the problem is an empty $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable, try to see the content of it wit a var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); die();    Remember that you can get the uri in the script which receives a request from your front end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel. With `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); die();` I get `string(8) "/de/test"` as result. 
But when I add the array code of your example, I still get the mentioned error message.

That is the correct part of the URL to my test file.

Comment: what is the content of $uriSegments?

Comment: the content of $uriSegments is "de".

Comment: Ok, check the line $uriSegments = explode("/", parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)); because it will return an array an it seems that return a string. Try to modify it for getting an array with this similar structure. ["", "de"];

Comment: Hi Daniel, sorry I didn't understood, what I should test exactly.

Is there not a typical cause for the mentioned error? I tested exact the code you posted in your first answer.

Comment: I would like so much to solve the task. If there's anybody who has an idea what could be the cause for the error message with the code from daniel, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: To access to an associative array in the main objective of my answer, first you need to get the language, try to do this echo $array[$language]["label"]; //get label
ensure that the $language variable has an string with the language for example "de" without spaces. If you have an error please past it completely.